# Choose photo from camera

Tags: android, image, camera, android-contentprovider, android-gallery

When I tested app I faced with one problem. The fact is that I need take photos for post. I wrote own gallery, the method that loads all the pictures looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

        String jpgExtension = "jpeg";
        String pngExtension = "png";
        String jpgMimeType = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(jpgExtension);
        String pngMimeType = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(pngExtension);

        Log.d("MIME", jpgMimeType + "; " + pngMimeType);

        final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? OR " +
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { jpgMimeType, pngMimeType };

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
        };

        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);
    }
```

When I take photo from camera (first item) and go back to my gallery, the content provider reload Loader and shows my photo with others.

For get photo from camera I use this tutorial. 
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery
It works good. But there is the problem with photo duplicate on some devices: 
[image]
When I tested it on emulator (google nexus 5) all is fine. But when I tested it on my device Lg G2 the taken image from camera showed twice. Because Lg and others devices uses own camera which saves photo to gallery too. How can I fix it?

My code:

```
@InstanceState
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,    Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
        galleryAddPic();
    }
}

//take photo from camera
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go

        try {
            File photoFile = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             .....
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File photoFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android Gallery is the best practice!